# Adobe Animate CC ActionScripts3 error

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to using StageWebView in Animate CC 2017, below error show when Test:

"Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1, Column 10   1037: Packages cannot be nested."

Document is empty, in frame 1 i added code.

```
 package { 
    import flash.display.*; 
    import flash.geom.Rectangle; 
    import flash.media.StageWebView; 
    public class WebView extends Sprite 
    { 
        public var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 
        public function WebView() 
        {     
            var htmlString:String = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" + 
            "<html><script type=text/javascript>" + 
            "function callURI(){" + 
            "alert(\"You clicked me!!\");"+ 
            "}</script><body>" + 
            "<p><a href=javascript:callURI()>Click Me</a></p>" + 
            "</body></html>"; 
            webView.stage = this.stage; 
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight ); 
            webView.loadString( htmlString ); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to put classes as frame script. Create WebView.as file in the same folder your *.fla source is, then assign it as a root document File > Publish Settings > AS3 Settings > Document class > WebView

Comment: An older [**Tutorial**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233) but it gives you visual hint about the process. PS: Code in timeline is **already** inside a `package` and has own `class` so don't put extra code that says _"create my new package with this class called webView"_, now you have two packages in one app, which makes an error. Keep only the **imports**, **vars** and **functions** then it should work. Make sure you are compiling an AIR app.

Comment: Ok i did it. error not appear but nothing show. blank screen.

Comment: I compiled for windows and android, still just blank page.

Comment: Please add the addressing @AliKazemi to let us know which advice you've tried.